# How to inject values to various constructors in spring

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

Hi I am new to spring technology.
I have a class called Employee as follows which has 2 constructors with different argument types.
I am able to inject values to one of the constructors as described in the xml file.
May I know how to inject value to other constructor as well using constructor injection. 
I tried various possibilities but unable to figure out how to do it.

```
public class Employee {
    private int eno ;
    private String name ;
    private double salary ;
    private String desig ;

    public Employee(int eno, String name) {
        this.eno = eno;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Employee(double salary, String desig) {
        this.salary = salary;
        this.desig = desig;
    }

    public void showInjectedValues() {
        System.out.println("Eno : " + eno);
        System.out.println("name : " + name);
        System.out.println("salary : " + salary);
        System.out.println("desig : " + desig);
    }

}
```

Trying to inject with spring.xml and the Java class for Injection is as follows:

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class InjectionTest {
    static ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("springconfig.xml");

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Employee employee = (Employee) applicationContext.getBean("employee");
        employee.showInjectedValues();

    }

}
```

applicationContext.xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd">

    <bean id="employee" class="com.vidvaan.spring.Employee">

        <constructor-arg value="2000" index="0" type="double" />
        <constructor-arg value="team lead" index="1"
            type="java.lang.String"     />

    </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: You could create another bean with a different id, but of the same class, and change the constructor args.

Answer (score 2):

Well,  that is not possible. What you are asking is
 **call two constructors to create one object.**
This doesn't make any sense. (Just read the above line again).

You can always place multiple objects of the same class on the spring context, calling a different constructor in each case.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd">

     <bean id="otherEmployee" class="com.vidvaan.spring.Employee">

            <constructor-arg value="100" index="0" type="int" />
            <constructor-arg value="team lead" index="1"
                type="java.lang.String"     />

        </bean>

    <bean id="employee" class="com.vidvaan.spring.Employee">

        <constructor-arg value="2000" index="0" type="double" />
        <constructor-arg value="team lead" index="1"
            type="java.lang.String"     />

    </bean>
</beans>
```

what you can do is create a constructor with all four arguments and pass null for objects which you don't want to initilize
or You can have a constructor with some arguments and others you can set through Field Injection `<property name = ...>`

Comment: Yes but the output is not as expected. Eno : 0
name : null
salary : 2000.0
desig : team lead
Eno : 123
name : Employee
salary : 0.0
desig : null first 2 values are being passed null for first bean and last 2 values are being null in case of 2nd bean. Hope you got the point

Comment: This is helpful. Was trying to figure out how to add static values in a bean outside of self-defined classes.

Answer (score 1):

```
You can create a another bean like this for different arguments: 
 <bean id = "employeeBean" class = "com.vidvaan.spring.Employee">
      <constructor-arg type = "int" value = "2001"/>
      <constructor-arg type = "java.lang.String" value = "Employee"/>
   </bean>
```